# Extending plot line past the last tick mark

Tags: pgfplots

The plot lines end at the last tick mark that falls into the domain.
Is it possible to extend the lines all the way past the mark and to the edge of the chart box?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,scale=2.2]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    restrict y to domain=-50:50,
    legend entries={$d=-2$,$d=-1$,$d=0$,$d=1$,$d=2$},legend pos=north west]
]
\foreach \d in {-2, ..., 2}
{
    \addplot[solid, every mark/.append style={fill=blue}, mark=*, mark size=1]{(x-\d)^3};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the desired results by explicitly defining the domain as `domain=-4:4`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,scale=2.2]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    restrict y to domain=-50:50,
    legend entries={$d=-2$,$d=-1$,$d=0$,$d=1$,$d=2$},legend pos=north west]
]
\foreach \d in {-2, ..., 2}
{
    \addplot[solid, every mark/.append style={fill=blue}, mark=*, mark size=1, domain=-4:4]{(x-\d)^3};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```